# Android inflating views from other layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm relatively new to android development and I'm trying to find a way to inflate a view repeatedly each time when a button is pressed, in a different location, so every inflated view has its own position:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class teamCreateScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.team_locate_layout);
}
public void createTeam(View view) {
    final RelativeLayout rlTeam = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlTeam);
    View teamBox = View.inflate(this, R.layout.team_box, rlTeam);

    final TextView teamBoxView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_task_box);
    teamBoxView.setX(0);
    teamBoxView.setY(230);
}
}
```

The XML code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rlTeam">

<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/teamAddBtn"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:onClick="createTeam"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML code of the view that's being inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/team_task_box"
    android:text="New Team" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to use the same view to inflate multiple boxes with different coordinates in the layout. Every time I press the button to inflate the view again it inflates the box in the same coordinates so they overlap. I need to make the second box to appear to the first one's right, the third below 1st and so on, much like a grid of boxes.

Comment: Where are you inflating this layout? And you don't have an button onClickListener

Comment: I'm inflating the TextView in the second XML example into the first one if that answers your question. I'm sorry but im fresh to inflating things :)

Comment: I have an onClick thing inside the first XML layout, I thought it does the same thing as the onClickListener?

Comment: please post the full code!

Comment: This is the full code associated with the problem, everything before is working just fine and as intended

Comment: try the code and tell me whether it works or not! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and tell me whether it works. Remove the inflating of layout

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class teamCreateScreen extends Activity {

int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.team_locate_layout);
}
public void createTeam(View view) {
   final RelativeLayout rlTeam = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlTeam);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   if(tv.getId()>0) {
      relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
   }
   tv.setId(i);
   r1Team.addView(tv, relativeParams);
   i++;
}
}
```

Declare **int i=0;** as a global variable and increment it in the **createTeam()** method.

Comment: It does, thank you! :) But this wasn't the problem. The real problem is that i can't figure out how to set the inflated views to their intended positions. The first one as in the code above was set to appear x(0) and y(230), but when i add a second one it still counts it as the same view (probably due to the id) and set the first one in different coordinates instead of the second one. My question was how to make so i could use a single view and add a bunch of those while still retaining control over each one so i could place them where i want on screen. Sorry if i wasnt clear with the question

Comment: Create TextView dynamically instead of giving it in the layout

Comment: Once again, sorry for my newbieness, but how do i create a TextView dinamically? Any chance you could give me an example?

Comment: it says that operator '!=' cannot be applied to integer 'null'

Comment: tv.setId(String.format("tv"+i); also there's something wrong with this part it shows an error on the semicolon

Comment: 1 error

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.609 secs

Comment: can you check the code that i posted below? have i done it correctly?

Comment: I said make **i** global and I modified my code yet again

Comment: how do i make it global? :D im so sorry i owe you so much for all the help

Comment: All errors are gone but nothing appears on the screen when i press the button. I might be able to work it out myself as you helped so much and im extremely grateful for that :) I don't want to bother you any further but if you know why its nothing's showing up i would be glad to hear what you have to say. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Umm i think i found whats wrong. (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) it asks me to import a class (the android.widget... that stuff) and there's a ton of options. which one do i need to import?

Comment: well out of that ton of options, this one is probably the only one that's not listed

Comment: Okay, figured that out but still, compiling it and pressing the button makes the views to be added on top of each other, and not in the manner i need them to. Just to remind how it should look: the button on top, the first view below the button, the 2nd view to the right of the 1st view, the 3rd view below 1st view, the 4th view to the right of 3rd and below 2nd and so on